# Asynchronous API call to self in symfony 3 / php / guzzle

Tags: php, asynchronous, symfony, guzzle

I've built an Rest / Cors API with Symfony 3.

I have some heavy computation that requires quite some time to complete (2 or 3 minutes). The code is already optimized and there's not much I can do on this side.

The result of the computation will be displayed in another screen so I don't need to wait. Real computation errors will be stored and shown in the second screen.

So I decided to "split" my code in 2 bits :

- a /prepare route which gets all the parameters and retrieves all the items to process
- a /compute route which does the actual computation
- /prepare calls /compute with Guzzle (using a bundle) using requestAsync

While this works, it has some major drawbacks to me :

- the API knows its own full external URL so that /prepare can call /compute : extra work + risk at deploy if someone uses the wrong URL ex: LIVE URL on QA, etc.
- this is an extra network call I don't need at all
- requestAsync doesn't start the request until I call wait() so I lowered the timeout to 1 second and caught the exception until a better solution is found.
- functional test is a right pain. What's the URL of the phpunit WebTestCase environnement again ? :)

I've tackled this kind of problems so many times in Java with elegant built-in tools / 3rd party lib (thread pools, Executors, JMS, etc.) but I couldn't find anything ticking all the boxes for PHP.

Comment: Enqueue task and execute it in background. Look at RabbitMQ.

Comment: looks like it requires a new tool to deploy and manage. Feels like it's an overkill. I'd much prefer some self contained Symfony Bundle.

Comment: That's most elegant way to resolve this kind of problems in PHP. True, you need to install one more package, but in this way you get reliable tool, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, and you are following some common pattern, what makes it easier to reason about for other devs. Rabbit itself is very simple, there is bundle which allows you to easily integrate it with sf.

Comment: @vivien.destpern Did you find any solution for this problem ? I am facing the same issue. I have created REST APIs using Symfony 3 and wanted to make some API calls partially asynchronous.

Comment: After years, I realise now the best was and is still an external tool. Yes it's painful because it is yet another tool but some tools are worth investigating. As of today, i'd do the same with step functions and lambdas. Step function would coordinate the calls and I would fire all my lambdas at the same time.